# Can CRISPR-cas9 be used to insert a large gene?

Tags: crispr, cas9

I would like to insert a 1500 bp or longer gene to the broken site in E.coli (or may be *bacillus subtilis* which support NHEJ) after cut with Crispr-Cas9. Is this possible for both NHEJ or HDR?

Comment: CRIPSR-Cas9 can be used in eukaryotes to insert much larger fragments (using two different sgRNAs and HDR), so in in principle this should be possible - I'm not sure if it will work in bacteria though.

Comment: @Nicolai thank you very much, can only one sgRNA work?